# Can not call Task.Run() at backgroundTask

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile, background-task

I want to do something in thread at background task, so I tried using Task.Run() but it does not work.

Anyone can show me another way to create thread in background task.

This is my code:

```
   public sealed class KatzBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
   {

    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        RawNotification notification = (RawNotification)taskInstance.TriggerDetails;
        string content = notification.Content;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content);
        testLoop();
    }

    async void testLoop()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
       {
           int myCounter = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
           {
               myCounter++;
                //String str = String.Format(": {0}", myCounter);
                Debug.WriteLine("testLoop runtimeComponent : " + myCounter);
           }
       }
       );

    }
}
```

When I remove `await Task.Run()` for loops can run normally, but when I don't remove it, for loop can not run.

Comment: You should never be doing `async void` unless you are writing a event handler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run tasks or use await - async pattern in your background tasks you need to use deferrals otherwise your task can terminate unexpectedly when it reaches the end of the `Run` method.

Read more in the official documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task)

Here's how you would implement task deferral in your code:

```
public sealed class KatzBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral(); 
    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        RawNotification notification = (RawNotification)taskInstance.TriggerDetails;
        string content = notification.Content;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content);
        await testLoop();
        _deferral.Complete();
    }

    async Task testLoop()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
           int myCounter = 0;
           for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
           {
               myCounter++;
               //String str = String.Format(": {0}", myCounter);
              Debug.WriteLine("testLoop runtimeComponent : " + myCounter);
           }
       }
   )

}
```

Comment: You need to fix those `async void` too, right now `await testLoop();` won't compile.

Comment: It still won't compile because `testLoop` returns `void` instead of `Task`

Comment: damn, this is what happens when you answer with no access to your dev machine.